# What does the meta_data variable means in the alpha vantage library?

Tags: python, metadata, cryptocurrency, alpha-vantage

When you add meta_data to the variable, what is that exactly?

For example:

```
from alpha_vantage.cryptocurrencies import CryptoCurrencies
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

key = '_____________________'

cc = CryptoCurrencies(key, output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = cc.get_digital_currency_daily(symbol='BTC', market='CNY')
```

Comment: what is `cc` - it's not defined in your code.

Comment: Check out the concept of unpacking. `get_digital_currency_daily()` returns 2 values.